# Visual Studio not deploying to iOS Simulator

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I have two iOS apps that I am building using Visual Studio. One of them deploys to the iOS simulator on my build mac and starts as expected. However when I build the other one Visual Studio displays the following message and the app doesn't run or even deploy (ie, there's no icon) on the simulator.

[image: Visual Studio message: Please Start the Application]

The message obviously mentions the fact that the app is signed with a Distribution provisioning profile, but a) that is the case with both apps and b) according to the message it has/should still be deployed.

The only difference that I can see between the two profiles is that the one that works includes "App Groups" in its "Enabled Services".

There are no other messages as far as I can see.

What could be causing this difference between the two apps, and how can I get the second app to at least deploy to the simulator?

Comment: I'll add this as a comment, because it's a horrible answer, but I've had instances where the VS project got so messed up that I had to take a working one (i.e. which worked on the sim or actual device), clean it out, then copy one-by-one the source from the non-working one, just to get a proper deploying project again. :( That said that's not happened with the most recent versions of Xamarin anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Under the iOS Bundle Signing section in project properties in VS, select the Signing Identity to be Developer (automatic).

Make sure on the Mac machine that compiles the project, you have the correct profile setup in XCode to be the certificate from the keychain access.  That can be found under XCode > Preferences.  Then make sure the same Apple ID is added under accounts and select Manage Certificates from the profile to make sure your certificate is linked.

then the error should not appear.

Comment: Just changing the Signing Identity to "Developer (automatic)" (as mentioned in the first paragraph) did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the provisional profile of distribution type. Go to https://developer.apple.com and create a similar provisional profile which is of development type.

download it on your pc and start using the latest provisional profile, you might resolve the error.